# Watson conversation API returns empty output for yes and no input

Tags: watson-conversation

I've set up a very simple script and part of it requires a yes or no response from the user.

When I test the script through the script builder at ibmwatsonconversation.com the script works fine.

But when I'm testing it through Postman making HTTP POST requests when I get to the part that requires a yes or no answer the output node is always

```
"output": {
"log_messages": [],
"text": [],
"nodes_visited": [
  "node_25_1480610375023"
]},
```

The previous two nodes in the conversation work fine.

I have set up intents for yes and no, see images below:
[image: yes intent]
[image: no intent]

The dialog is as follows:

[image: dialog]

Here's the chain of requests / responses:

```
{"input": {"text": "hello"}}

"output": {"log_messages": [],"text": ["Welcome to the KMBC IT help desk.How can I help you?"],"nodes_visited": ["node_1_1480509441272"]},
```

then

```
{"input": {"text": "my laptop is broken"}}

"output": {
"log_messages": [],
"text": [
  "I'm sorry to hear that your laptop isn't working. \n\nI need you to check a couple of things for me, is that ok?"
],
"nodes_visited": [
  "node_3_1480509642420",
  "node_19_1480518011225"
]},
```

finally

```
{"input": {"text": "yes"}}

"output": {
"log_messages": [],
"text": [],
"nodes_visited": [
  "node_25_1480610375023"
]},
```

Works fine inside the "Try it out" panel within the workspace:

[image]

Full JSON request / response:

```
{"input": {"text": "hello"}}

{"intents": [{"intent": "greetings","confidence": 1}],"entities": [],"input": {"text": "hello"},"output": {"log_messages": [],"text": ["Welcome to the KMBC IT help desk. How can I help you?"],"nodes_visited": ["node_1_1480509441272"]},"context": {"conversation_id": "4b5b1858-ae4e-4907-a3ab-c49abf601fd3","system": {
  "dialog_stack": [
    {
      "dialog_node": "root"
    }
  ],
  "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
  "dialog_request_counter": 1
}}}


{"input": {"text": "laptop broken"}}
{"intents": [{"intent": "complaint","confidence": 0.989692384334575}],"entities": [
{"entity": "hardware",
  "location": [
    0,
    6
  ],
  "value": "laptop"
}],"input": {"text": "laptop broken"},"output": {"log_messages": [],"text": ["I'm sorry to hear that your laptop isn't working. \n\nI need you to check a couple of things for me, is that ok?"],"nodes_visited": ["node_3_1480509642420",
  "node_19_1480518011225"]},"context": {
"conversation_id": "b53dff12-9252-4b7e-abe8-7b45f561d394",
"system": {"dialog_stack": [{"dialog_node": "node_19_1480518011225"}],
  "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
  "dialog_request_counter": 1}}}


{"input": {"text": "yes"}}
{"intents": [{"intent": "yes","confidence": 1}],"entities": [],"input": {"text": "yes"},"output": {"log_messages": [],"text": [],"nodes_visited": ["node_25_1480610375023"]},"context": {"conversation_id": "b9ddc5b0-5f3c-423f-9bbe-5a1ef013c175","system": {"dialog_stack": [{"dialog_node": "root"}],"dialog_turn_counter": 1,"dialog_request_counter": 1}}}
```

Comment: Can you supply a small example? One thing to do is download the JSON file, and look for that node ID to see what node you are hitting.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty I have edited my post to include some screen grabs from the Watson workspace and the JSON request / responses.

Comment: You need to show the full request / response JSON.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty I have added the full JSON request / response for each of the three conversation parts.

Comment: hi mark, you may need to share your workspace json. Looking at the json above you are hitting the correct intent #yes. But this is doing so at node 25. We would need to actual see the code/json for node 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the full JSON request/response, your issue is here (actually it's also in the previous call, but that works by concidence):

```
{"input": {"text": "yes"}}
```

Conversation is stateless, so you need to send back in the context object you received previously. Otherwise the system doesn't know where to continue. The following request object should look like this:

```
{
"input": {"text": "yes"},
"context": {
    "conversation_id": "b53dff12-9252-4b7e-abe8-7b45f561d394",
    "system": {
        "dialog_stack": [{"dialog_node": "node_19_1480518011225"}],
        "dialog_turn_counter": 1,
        "dialog_request_counter": 1
    }
}
```

I would recommend to use the Watson Developer Cloud SDK to manage this for you.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually created a yes and no intent ?
There is a lot of debate about the best process to handle yes and no responses. But I have found that by creating a yes and no intent, with example "yes" and "No" responses works well. 
Your example questions for these intents could include responses like "ok", "yess", "on no","yes please" etc.

Comment: yes I have set up yes and no intents... see edited OP for more info.